# How do I get last 32 bytes in Java

Tags: javascript, java, base64, byte, bytebuffer

How do I get last 32 bytes in Java?

I tried this but the result is not same with javascript output.

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(privateKeyBytes, privateKeyBytes.length - 32, privateKeyBytes.length);
byte[] publicKeyBytes32 = Arrays.copyOfRange(publicKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes.length - 32, publicKeyBytes.length);
```

Here is the code in reference code achieved inJavascript:

```
const computeSecretX25519 = (privKey, PubKey) => {
let privateKey = Buffer.from(privKey,'base64');
let publicKey = Buffer.from(PubKey, 'base64');

// real value is at last 32 bytes
const KEY_LENGTH = 32;
privateKey = privateKey.slice(privateKey.length - KEY_LENGTH);
publicKey = publicKey.slice(publicKey.length - KEY_LENGTH);

return sharedKey(privateKey, publicKey);
};
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? could you post sample input and output?

Comment: maybe you are loading the keys differently in java than in javascript? Because that array copy seems to be correct

Comment: @rajan.kali

Actual privateKey: MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VuBCIEIFjvZbCs2hHFVlaCZkmXj1xObH0kX1HRpX+ObvLc1EZ9
    javascript: WO9lsKzaEcVWVoJmSZePXE5sfSRfUdGlf45u8tzURn0=    Java: VmxhQ1prbVhqMXhPYkgwa1gxSFJwWCtPYnZMYzFFWjk=